# I installed Xamarin Studio Community, and cannot access CocosSharp templates or add-ins

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin-studio, cocossharp

I recently downloaded and installed Xamarin Studio and would like to try using the CocosSharp libraries for a game idea I have in mind. The problem is I don't seem to have access to CocosSharp. The templates are not appearing in the Xamarin Studio template selection, and they are not appearing in the add-in manager either (only MonoGame is there, which I installed as well). I even tried to download the NuGet package, which told me CocosSharp is already installed.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Am I allowed to use CocosSharp with Xamarin Studio Community edition?

Any advice helps, there seems to be no information anywhere on this topic.

Comment: Create the project, install CocosSharp Nuget, start writing code. What templates you expect?

Comment: I think it would help if the title of your question poses a question or describes your actual problem like "I installed Xamarin Studio Community, but no templates are available in Template selection or Add-in manager". Unfortunately I don't know why that happens.

Comment: Have you gone over this guide? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/

Answer (score 0):

The add-in manager for cocossharp is not compatible with the latest xamarin studio. The docs are not up to date.

You can either start a new solution (multiplatform single view app) and add the Cocosharp nuget (to all projects) or take an example project and change that.

Comment: Hi, I gave up on implementing cocossharp because after several attempts of adding the nuget I just keep getting errors...
Do you have any possible solutions?
This is beginning to be very frustrating.